# Syntax grammar issues in C# code. Creating logic errors within code

Tags: c#

The value for pi can be created with this order:
4 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9.

Write a Windows Forms Application that prompts the user for a number of terms and CALCULATES the value of the sequence for the specified number of terms. I cannot  round my resulting value.

just imagine if this was the design page (I am using Visual Studio 2017)

---

Enter # of terms:  [        ]

[CALCULATE] //this is a button

(*label 2) Approximate the value of pi after [Insert Text-box Input Value] terms.

(*label 3) [Value of pi Printed]

---

So, how do I get the correct input of the textbox? 
and get both messages printed?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Need Variable names for input of textbox. Textbox must be a double value 

        if termsTextBox?
        //termsTextBox is the name of the textbox I named. 

    }

    private void termsTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Approximate value of pi after" + "" + "terms");
        Console.WriteLine(Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip for your future: Beyond an introductory lesson, avoid writing lengthy logic as "code under buttons" (that is, in event handlers). Instead write a separate class and delegate to that from the event handler. This makes code much more testable and keeps the user interface concerns separate from other application logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
double double; 
string textValue = termsTextBox.Text.Trim(); 
if (textValue != "") 
{ 
    double = Convert.ToDouble(textValue); 
}
```

Although you should also use a try/catch to make sure the input can actually be converted without error.

Comment: Inputs that cannot be successfully converted are *expected* when dealing with user input. Therefore, no, they shouldn't be using `try`/`catch` to deal with issues. They should be using [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know, but the question seems like a homework question, and I just assumed they hadn't covered try/catches. Perhaps I assumed too much though

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be as following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void termTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numberOfTerms;
        if (Int32.TryParse(termTextBox.Text, out numberOfTerms) && numberOfTerms > 0)
        {  
          this.approxLbl.Text = "Approximate the value of pi after " + numberOfTerms + " terms";
          this.calculateBtn.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.approxLbl.Text = "Number of terms must be a positive integer.";
        }
    }

    private void calculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the approximation of pi is given by 4/1 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9 ... number of terms
        double numerator = 4;
        double denominator = 1;

        int numberOfTerms;
        Int32.TryParse(termTextBox.Text, out numberOfTerms);

        double approximation = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTerms; i++)
        {
            //change the operation each cycle
            if(i % 2 != 0)
            {
                approximation += numerator / denominator;
            }
            else
            {
                approximation -= numerator / denominator;
            }
            denominator += 2;
        }

        this.resultLbl.Text = "The approximation is " + approximation;
    }
}
```

Your form should look like this:
[image]

The result:[image]

Hope it helps